# Generating two-dimensional array of binaries in Python

Tags: python, list

So this is what im trying

```
list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement('01', 2))
```

but this is generating `[('0', '0'), ('0', '1'), ('1', '1')]`

I still need a `('1','0')` tuple, is there a way to make itertools also do combinations and order?

Comment: Rollback to Revision 3, **Don't change question**, If you have other doubt [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 5):

Use [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) instead:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.product('01', repeat=2))
[('0', '0'), ('0', '1'), ('1', '0'), ('1', '1')]
```

Comment: FYI, you answered this in 48th sec, since the question was posted. :(

Comment: @thefourtheye, in 48 secs with typo! Thank you for the correction.

Comment: seriously, i got as far as copy/pasting OP's base code by the time you'd posted