# Generating 2-d array of binary numbers in python

Tags: python, list

So this is what im trying in Python.`

```
input = []
for i in range(10):
  n = getBin(i, 4)
  input.append(n)
print input
```

It is giving as:

```
['0000', '0001', '0010', '0011', '0100', 
 '0101', '0110', '0111', '1000', '1001']
```

And what I need is as:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) with (0, 1) and 4 repeats:

```
input = [list(x) for x in itertools.product((0, 1), repeat=4)]
```

If you're ok with a `list` of `tuple`s rather than of `list`s, you can simply do:

```
input = list(itertools.product((0, 1), repeat=4))
```

Or simplest of all, if you will be iterating over it anyway, there's no need to make it a `list`:

```
input = itertools.product((0, 1), repeat=4)
```

Lastly, `(0, 1)` could be `range(2)`, but that's hardly an improvement

---

`itertools.product` generally tries to return in the same format you gave it. So by feeding a string, it returns a string. Feed it a list and it...almost returns a list (returns a tuple)

Comment: Not sure  but I think [OP don't want this technique](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21746347/1673391).

Comment: The first option is what i want.In the same way i want for floating points and the number will contain around 10 digits after point (ex. 0.0001221215). The number will vary from 0 to 2500.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, I assumed this new question was an implementation detail of the previous, as previous output was the input to this question. Using that knowledge, I'm changing the `itertools.product` in `getBin` to provide the solution without any additional layer of code

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan ok.. i m adding new question for the above

Comment: how can i save these binary numbers in txt file.Each line should contain 4 bits as from above question.

Answer (score 1):

Your `getBin` returns a binary number in string format, we convert each and every character to an integer with `int` and return a list.

```
result = [map(int, getBin(i,4)) for i in range(10)]
```

For example,

```
def getBin(number, total):
    return bin(number)[2:].zfill(total)

result = [map(int, getBin(i, 4)) for i in range(10)]

print result
```

**Output**

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: is `getBin` any library function?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Nope. OP hasn't shown how that is implemented. So, I had to implement it on my own. Its there in my answer itself. Please check.